# Can a SVN repository include/link-to an external git repository?

Tags: svn, git

I have a svn repository, R, that depends on a library, l, in another repository.

The goal is that when someone checks out R, they also check out l. We want l to still be in its own repository so that l can be updated without dependence on R.

I don't know much about external svn links, but I believe that when depending on a svn-based library one can link to it externally, 'ext'.

If l is in a git repository, can I do something similar? I'd like to preserve the goal stated above.

Answer (score 4):

[svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) is the way svn can be made to check out sources from more than one repository into one working copy. But it is only meant for dealing with svn repositories - it doesn't know how to check out a git repository.

You might be able to do it the other way 'round, by including an svn repository inside a git repository, using something like 'git svn'.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a script wrapper for svn co.

```
#!/bin/sh
svn co path://server/R svn-R
git clone path://server/l git-l
```

Or similar.